# I installed Active Directory on Windows 2012 R2, But now I can't log in VIA RDP

Tags: permissions, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

After installing the Directory Services Role and configuring and promoting the server to a domain controller the wizard automatically reboots my server.

After the reboot, I can no longer log in to the server as before (via RDP). What happened? This is a virtual server, so destroying it and starting over is an option, but after trying that 3 times  how do I avoid this problem in the first place?

And another question  is - can I install Active Directory without rebooting automatically?

Answer (score 0):

can you ping ? what is the ping out put looks firewall is blocking or allow connections only from computers running remote desktop with NLA is enabled.

Why don't you install team viewer and setup unattended access and see what happening.

Comment: I can ping and Finally, I can connect, problem was I tried to log in with the domain I entered without the .com at the end instead  of domain.com